# How to access props in a functional HOC?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have code similar to the following:

```
const HOC = (props, WrappedComponent) => {
    return (
       <>
          <WrappedComponent />
          <Icon className="props.iconStyles" />
       </>
     );
};
```

This is not actually valid code, but you can hopefully see what I'm trying to accomplish. I want to be able to use it in the following way:

```
<HOC iconStyles="icon-stuff">
    <TheComponentIWantToWrap>
</HOC>
```

How can I write this correctly, so as to be able to pass props through? I think I might need to be using `children` here too, not sure.

Comment: This isn't a HOC, a HOC is a function that takes in a component and returns a component. You're returning JSX directly, not a new component. ("higher order x" is a function that takes something of type x and returns something of type x)

Comment: Hmm.  I'm trying to understand the distinction. How do you differentiate a piece of JSX and its descendent tree from "a component"? Isn't that basically what a component is?

Comment: A component is a class or function that returns JSX (technically it returns react elements)

Comment: So....isn't `HOC` a function that returns JSX? And is thus an HOC? Edit: Ohhhhhh you mean it would have to return a function itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It would be something like this.

```js
const HOC = (WrappedComponent) => {

  const MyComponent = props => {
    return (
       <>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
          <Icon className={props.iconStyles} />
       </>
     );
   }
   
  return MyComponent;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

An `HOC` is a funtion which returns a `Component` and usually inject some `props` on it. You should separate concerns. An actual `HOC` should look like this

```
const withFoo = Component =>{
    return props =>{
        return <Component injectedProps='foo' />
    }
}
```

And be called like this

```
const Component = withFoo(({ injectedProps }) =>{
    return <jsx />
})
```

If you want to merge arbitrary `props` as well try to spread the `props` passed to `Component`

```
const withFoo = Wrapped =>{
    return props =>{
        return <Wrapped injectedProps='foo' {...props}/>
    }
}

<Component propsToBeSpreaded='bar' />
```

If you prefer you can create an aditional layer.

- `HOC` injects some props in a `Container`
- `Container` accepts arbitrary `props`
- `Container` renders `children`

The code

```
   const withHoc = Container =>{
        return () => <Container injected='foo' />
    }

    const Container = withHoc(({ children, injected, ...aditionalProps}) =>{
         return(
             <div {...aditionalProps}>
                 { children }
             </div>
         )
    })
```

And call it like

```
const FinalComp = () =>{
    return <Container foo='foo'> <span /> </Container>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A higher-order component would return another component (another function in this case). A component is a function that returns JSX.

```js
const HOC = (Component) => {
  return function WrappedComponent(props) {
    return (
       <>
          <Component {...props} />
          <Icon className="props.iconStyles" />
       </>
     );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could still pass down props along with a Component to be enhanced (as per your original approach which you think is wrong) It is right since -

> HOCs are not part of React API. They emerge from React's nature of composition.

So your HOC usage is -

```js
const EnhancedComponent = higherOrderComponent(WrappedComponent, anyProps);
```

**Points to note:**

1. Your HOC takes in a Component and returns a Component (enhanced or not)

```js
    const higherOrderComponent = (WrappedComponent, anyProps) => {
        return class extends React.Component {
            // Component body
        }
    }
```

2. Don’t Mutate the Original Component. Use Composition.
3. Pass Unrelated Props Through to the Wrapped Component.

```js
    const higherOrderComponent = (WrappedComponent, anyProps) => {
        return class extends React.Component {
            render() {
                const { HOCProp, ...compProps } = this.props;
                return (
                    <WrappedComponent
                        ...compProps,
                        someProp={anyProps.someProp}
                    />
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Considering all this, your HOC would look like this -

```js
    const withWrappedIcon = (CompToWrap, iconStyle) => {
        return (
           <Icon className={iconStyle}>
              <CompToWrap />
           </Icon>
        );
    }
```